# When system reset I get "git error object file is empty"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

While writing a commit and trying to push to bitbucket failed and I got an error
I tried to do everything like in this article https://howto.lintel.in/fix-git-object-file-empty-error/

But now I have a link to another empty file and an additional error for refs/heads/master

```
Checking objects: 100% (44450/44450), done.
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry e532275d3cf4cd02101c28d9ef46d541cb80d570
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry e532275d3cf4cd02101c28d9ef46d541cb80d570
error: object file .git/objects/72/291ff58e5822169ad13acc31c5edbdd2f67afb is empty
fatal: loose object 72291ff58e5822169ad13acc31c5edbdd2f67afb (stored in .git/objects/72/291ff58e5822169ad13acc31c5edbdd2f67afb) is corrupt
```

How do I fix this further, nothing helps. Am I even ready to roll back all changes to the current origin/master or is there still some correct way?

I will be grateful for help

Comment: You have a damaged repository. Your title mentions "system reset": do you mean your computer *crashed?* If so, it was probably the OS crashing, or the power failing, or whatever it was that took the system down, that corrupted the repository. If not, figure out what cause the repository corruption. You'll likely need to re-clone and re-create your work.

Comment: Note that it's unwise to store the `.git` repository directory in a cloud-synced folder. Cloud-syncing software is known to damage Git repositories in practice. Store the `.git` locally, on the laptop's drive (assuming it's a laptop), if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, there was a restart of the computer, I did a git reset, and when I tried to stash / pop + commit => the error returned, after that, I took out the new code that was in the damaged commit from one vscode window to another and copy / paste - the error returned, because file was not found or corrupted. I realized that in this way I copy not only the code - I got around it in a different way, and the commits began to be written normally again.